SonarQube: Could not find a default branch for project
In gitlab pipeline with self host on my machine, i wrote the script:
sonarscanner begin /k:"pkey" /n:"pname" /d:sonar.host.url="https://sonarcloud.io" /v:"1.0" /d:sonar.token="$SONAR_TOKEN" /o:"organization"

Got:
SonarScanner for MSBuild 6.2 
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
00:27:05.624  Updating build integration targets...
00:27:06.466  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
00:27:08.086  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for cs...
00:27:08.09  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
00:27:08.09  Processing plugin: csharp version 9.25.1.91650
00:27:08.18  Processing plugin: vbnet version 9.25.1.91650
00:27:08.181  Processing plugin: securitycsharpfrontend version 10.6.0-M1.31001
00:27:08.874  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for vbnet...
00:27:08.874  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
00:27:08.875  Processing plugin: csharp version 9.25.1.91650
00:27:08.875  Processing plugin: vbnet version 9.25.1.91650
00:27:09.173  Downloading cache. Project key: pkey, branch: main.
00:27:09.946  Cache data is empty. A full analysis will be performed.
00:27:10.125  Pre-processing succeeded.

msbuild /src/mtrial.sln

sonarscanner end /d:sonar.token="$SONAR_TOKEN"

but i got this error:
ERROR: Could not find a default branch for project with key 'pkey'. Make sure project exists.
If i try the script locally in powershell, it run successfully and the project is created normally on sonarcloud.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Most likely you've forgotten to setup your project in the SonarCloud. Login to the website and setup a project linked to your repository.

I had a similar issue, although my project was already set up on SonarQube cloud.
What fixed it for me was:

In SonarQube cloud: open "Settings -> Analysis Method" and disable automatic analysis (as is recommended for analysis method "with Github Actions")
click on "With Github Actions"
in Github set the token as displayed here "e.g. via `gh secret set SONAR_TOKEN"
click on "Other (for JS, TS, Go, Python, PHP ...)"
check and set the projectKey according to what is listed in the sample file. For me it was a combination of organization and actual project key, not the name of the project in SonarQube!

